Can I use Blaster Advanced Dry Lube on electric oven door hinges without fear of combustion?
Can I use "Blaster Advanced Dry Lube" to lubricate the oven door hinges?

i would not use that, but silicone grease

Any kind of grease will have a tendency to accumulate crumbs and other debris, but I guess you're not eating off the oven hinges.

I would avoid it near hot items. It has a crazy number of ingredients that I would be uncomfortable having around heat.  It is also of unknown toxicity

Distillates, petroleum, light distillate hydrotreating process, low-boiling
Carbon dioxide
Aluminum oxide
Cyclohexane


10.4. Conditions to avoid
Sources of ignition. Heat. Incompatible materials.


Boiling point : 90 – 98 °C (195-208 °F)

Source - their datasheet.
